# ContextMenu with ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView:

```
ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
```

I registered a context menu to this ListView:

```
registerForContextMenu(lst);
```

I want to show the ContextMenu onItemClickListener and I do it with:

```
lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        openContextMenu(view);
    }

});
```

That's all very well, but if I do a long press on ListView item, my context menu is showing the same. How can I show my ContextMenu only for short click on item?

Please tell me if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you say. I've just tried to remove `registerForContextMenu()`, if I do, my ContextMenu is not showing with ShortClick and LongClick. I want show only on ShortClick.

Comment: I resolved showing ContextMenu on long click and not in short click by called `showContextMenu()` instead of `openContextMenu()`. Thanks anyway for your reply.